# ActiveAndroid error Failed to Read Row 0, Column -1 from a CursorWindow?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I am trying to query the database to get all `Tree` objects however an error is thrown: `Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1021 rows, 15 columns.`

`Model`:

```
@Table(name = "TreeDetails")
public class Tree extends Model {

    public Tree(){
        //Mandatory Empty Constructor
        super();
    }

    @Column(name = "ScientificName")
    public String scientificName;
    public String getScientificName() {
        return scientificName;
    }

    public static List<Tree> getAll(){
        return new Select()
                .from(Tree.class)
                .orderBy("ScientificName Asc")
                .execute();
    }
}
```

In `Fragment`:

```
public void getTrees(){
        Log.e(TAG, "get trees");

        List<Tree> trees = Tree.getAll();
    }
```

Why am I getting this error. There are 15 columns in the db but I only need 1. The spelling of he column is `ScientificName`.

Comment: dump the cursor by calling DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor

Comment: seems like there is no such column in the table ... did you changed the DB version after you added this column? (i don;t know if activeandroid has it but it should)

Comment: @pskink Do you need a cursor when using Active Android?

Comment: @Selvin No I'm on version 1.

Comment: That error is usually seen when performing a `Select("ColumnName")` instead of `Select("Id, ColumnName")`. Are your sure that's the code that's crashing?